# Common function for calling debugger; in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, javascript-debugger

How can I make a common function in my global.js to for calling debugger; in JS. I'll basically set a value whether to debug or not. I tried the following but it's not working. Any lead will be appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var debugModeVal = 1;
debugMode = function() 
{
  if(debugModeVal)
  {
    debugger;
  }
  return;
}
</script>
```

I am calling from my html file like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callAnotherFunction()
{
   debugMode;
}
</script>
```

Comment: You call a function by using parentheses `()`. `debbuger` is not a function.

Comment: also don't forget to add both scripts to the html page

Comment: @JanDvorak I didn't get what are you saying. How should I call debugMode function then? and How can I call debugger? return debugger;?

Comment: @13ruce1337 I have added both the function in the same HTML file.

Comment: I mean, use `debugMode()`

Comment: @JanDvorak It's working but not working like a debugger. I was thinking that debugger will stop where I am putting debugMode() function. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DixitChopra step out of the `debugMode` function to find yourself in the caller?

Answer (score 0):

use debugMode() instead of debugMode; in callAnotherFunction().

For debugging, use step out of the debugMode function to find yourself in the caller. Thanks to Jan Dvorak.